Как сделать телеграмма бота на Пайтон, который парсить несколько RSS (20-30)
Не могу найти вообще никакой информации по данной теме.
Пытался сам написать код на Пайтон, однако, парсинг 20-30 rss жрёт довольно много ресурсов. Может кто знает, как можно оптимизировать данный процесс?

Чтобы что-то оптимизировать, нужно смотреть то что уже есть. Не знаю что там может жрать ресурсы, максимум вы просто последовательно rss парсите, это может занять какое-то время. Как это исправить - например асинхронность использовать, собирать данные параллельно (через asyncio.gather), тогда будет меньше простоя во время ожидания ответов серверов.
